# Reading particular row from excel file without reading it completely

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

I have a very large excel file, above 30 MB. The excel file is for a state, and it contains many rows. Each row represents a village in the state. Now given the village name, I need to read the particular row from the excel file.

I am currently using `df = pd.read_excel()` to read the file and then finding the particular row using `df.loc`.

I would like to know if there is any approach in which I don't have to read in the complete file for extracting a single row. This is because reading the entire file takes a lot of time.

Any help/suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks !

Comment: use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)

Comment: I think the best way to do this is to get the file handle and iterate over the file line by line. This way you don't need to load the entire file into memory

Answer (score 1):

You can use the openpyxl module and iterate over your file.
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html